# Use jQuery to change text color inside any clicked block element

Tags: jquery

I need your help with something that should be simple, I hope :)

I have this html:

```
<div>div text</div>
<p>p text</p>
<span>span text</span>
<h1>h1 text</h1>
<ul>
  <li>some li text</li>
  <li>more li text</li>
</ul>
```

I need jQuery to color selected text to red every time that element is clicked. Now, there might be some other elements too so keep that in mind. Also, only selected element should change the color.

As an example here is some simple code that will do exactly what I need but only for div element:

```
  $('div').click(function() {
    $(this).css({'color':'red'}); 
  });
```

What is the simplest code to have the same functionality for all elements in html.

Thanks!

Comment: There should be your answer. You should accept one of a solutions below which you think best.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

css:

```
.highlight
{
   color: #f00;
}
```

javascript:

```
$('*').click(function(e) {
  $('*').removeClass('highlight');
  $(this).addClass('highlight');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

The first call removes the class from everything in case it was already higlighted.  That way, only one item at a time is highlighted.

Answer (score 8):

How about

```
$('*').click(function(e) {
  $(this).css('color', 'red');
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

I included the call to "stopPropagation()" to make sure that everything doesn't turn red due to event bubbling.

Of course, if you only want this effect inside some container, you could change the initial selector from "*" (every element in the DOM) to something like "#containerId *", to get every element in the container.

*edit* — I like @Geoff's answer - it's a lot classier :-)

Comment: Thanks Pointy, stopPropagation() was the missing link in my code :)

Comment: +1 for constraining to a container instead of just selecting *everything*